# Apache Ignite: can I create cache tables manually, using DDL statements?

Tags: ignite

Speaking about the latest version (currently 2.3). Seems like [old-way](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.1/docs/distributed-ddl) a little bit useless now.

If it is possible to create table(s) manually, here comes another question: how to map model POJO's fields and column names so I can fill in cache using DataStreamers. (@QuerySqlField.name, isn't it?)

Comment: You can create tables using both DDL or cache configuration. DDL is not an old way actually, and definitely not useless :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to populate cache with data, using DataStreamer, then you should create it using Java API, or by configuring it in Ignite XML configuration.

Tables can be configured, using `indexedTypes` or `queryEntities` properties in `CacheConfiguration`. Take a look at the documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-queries#section-query-configuration-by-annotations